# NodeJS streams - out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, out-of-memory

I was experimenting with nodejs streams and I came across something strange in my opinion.

#### Pipe to writable

```js
const {
  Writable,
  Readable
} = require('stream');

const myWritable = new Writable({
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    callback()
  },
});

const myReadable = new Readable({
  read() {
    this.push(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
  }
});

myReadable.pipe(myWritable);
```

This seemingly harmless code causes a linear memory increase and after 10 seconds the process stops with an out of memory error.

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Although this code isn't really meaningful, I still don't get why it consumes so much memory. I think, it should just create the buffer from the readable stream, pipe it into the writable and then just garbage collect everything.

#### Pipe to file

```js
const {
  Readable
} = require('stream');

const myWritable = require('fs').createWriteStream('/dev/null')

const myReadable = new Readable({
  read() {
    this.push(Buffer.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]))
  }
});

myReadable.pipe(myWritable);
```

In this scenario, that the write actually uses the file-system, the process runs just fine without any significant memory usage.

So, any thoughts of what is going on under the hood?